# Custom CSS properties in .Net MAUI

Tags: css, maui

I'm making a custom button control in .Net MAUI that has a property called "HoverColor". When using the control in XAML I would like to style the button using CSS, including setting the HoverColor.
So how can I add this custom CSS property?

I see from the MAUI source code that CSS properties are defined AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: StyleProperty("border-color", typeof(IBorderElement),  nameof(BorderElement.BorderColorProperty))]
[assembly: StyleProperty("border-radius", typeof(ICornerElement), nameof(CornerElement.CornerRadiusProperty))]
[assembly: StyleProperty("border-radius", typeof(Button), nameof(Button.CornerRadiusProperty))]
```

but StyleProperty is not accessible from my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://benetskyybogdan.medium.com/xamarin-forms-custom-css-properties-d75872bea20e) blog article, I found the Xamarin.Forms app [MagicGradients](https://github.com/mgierlasinski/MagicGradients) that has a StyleSheets helper class that can register new CSS properties using reflection. I copied the code and updated the namespaces for MAUI

```
public static class StyleSheets
{
    public static void RegisterStyle(string name, Type targetType, string bindablePropertyName)
    {
        var stylePropertyInfo = typeof(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar).GetProperty("StyleProperties", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var styleProperties = stylePropertyInfo?.GetValue(null);

        if (styleProperties == null)
            return;

        var stylePropertiesType = styleProperties.GetType();
        var styleAttributeType = typeof(StyleSheet).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StyleSheets.StylePropertyAttribute");
        var styleAttributeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(styleAttributeType, name, targetType, bindablePropertyName);

        var containsKeyMethod = stylePropertiesType.GetMethod("ContainsKey");
        if (containsKeyMethod == null)
            return;

        var containsKey = (bool)containsKeyMethod.Invoke(styleProperties, new object[] { name });
        if (containsKey)
        {
            var itemProperty = stylePropertiesType.GetProperty("Item");
            var attributes = itemProperty?.GetValue(styleProperties, new object[] { name });

            attributes?.GetType().GetMethod("Insert")?.Invoke(attributes, new[] { 0, styleAttributeInstance });
        }
        else
        {
            var styleListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(styleAttributeType);
            var styleList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(styleListType);
            styleList.Add(styleAttributeInstance);

            stylePropertiesType.GetMethod("Add")?.Invoke(styleProperties, new object[] { name, styleList });
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
StyleSheets.RegisterStyle("hover-color", typeof(ContentButton), nameof(ContentButton.HoverColorProperty));
```

and stylesheet file:

```
.RoundedButton {
    background: #FF6688;
    hover-color: #ffd800;
}
```

Comment: Just did. When I tried to accept my own answer when I wrote it, it said that I had to wait for two days before accepting it